Does Gap Limit Take into Account the Indexing of Master Keys?
For example, if I were to have a 2 of 2 multisig wallet constructed as follows:
wsh(sortedmulti(2,[deadb33f/1000000h]xpub.../<0;1>/*,[deadb33f/0h/1000000]xpub.../<0;1>/*))

Would a standard wallet with a gap limit of 20 have trouble finding the balance because of the 1,000,000 index BEFORE the xpubs(assuming there are 100 sats at index xpub/0/0)?

No. The gap limit only applies to the /* part at the end of the derivation paths. It is the result of the wallet software needing to guess how far to expand the * in order to look for your funds.
The /1000000h part of the derivation path is not automatically searched for, but imported/selected by the user, so the concern of gap limits does not apply.
